# Как включить сайт, если выбрал поврежденную тему в Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Сегодня устанавливал сайт и при установке возникла ошибки при активации темы. Я удалил тему, аналогично работы с плагином, однако сайт на WP не включился. Какой механизм восстанавливает сайт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А какая-то другая тема есть?
Попробуй в БД, в таблице <префикс>_options, изменить строку, где столбец option_name=current_theme. В столбец option_value впиши название другой, рабочей, темы, например так:

```
Twenty Fourteen
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня была та же проблема, когда в папке с темами не было никакой темы кроме поврежденной. Удалил поврежденную, добавил одну из тех, что идут по умолчанию и все само заработало. Вордпресс был 3.8.